# Json Serialization with JsonView Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class that I want to serialize ignoring some properties

```
public class User extends Model
{
    static class publicView{}

    @JsonView(publicView.class)
    private Long id;

    private String showName;

    @JsonView(publicView.class)
    private List<qQueue> callableQueues;

}
```

When I serialize without JsonView I usually do something like this

```
public JsonNode jsonSerialization()
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.convertValue(this, JsonNode.class);  
}
```

How can I serialize with the "publicView" class ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure the object mapper to include your `publicView.class` and exclude other fields as follows:

- Disable the `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` mapper feature.
- Enable the view for serialization via the `ObjectMapper#getSerializationConfig().withView()` method.

See [this page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) for reference.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonView1 {
    public static class publicView{}

    public static class User  {
        public User(Long id, String showName, List<String> callableQueues) {
            this.id = id;
            this.showName = showName;
            this.callableQueues = callableQueues;
        }
        @JsonView(publicView.class)
        public final Long id;

        public final String showName;

        @JsonView(publicView.class)
        public final List<String> callableQueues;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User(123l, "name", Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
        mapper.setConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
                .withView(publicView.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.convertValue(user, JsonNode.class));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"id":123,"callableQueues":["a","b"]}
```

Comment: I can not find the setConfig method, it may be possible that this method has changed?

Comment: Yes, this method has been added in version 2.0. For 1.X there are other methods. Refer to this page: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews

Comment: I did not need to have the line `mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);`. It worked just great with `mapper.setConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
                .withView(publicView.class));`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Alexey Gavrilov I have found a solution, It may not be the most appropriate but works.

```
public JsonNode jsonSerialization()
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try 
    {
        mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
        return Json.parse(mapper.writerWithView(publicView.class).writeValueAsString(this));
    } 
    catch (JsonProcessingException ex) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```