# How to disallow updating of a field while patching with Java JSON Patch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, json-patch

I have a spring boot project containing a Pojo named Person and a controller which allows a user to get a person by Id and to Patch the Person object so that it's name or/and surname could be updated.

The Person Pojo (simplified for example purposes)

```
class Person {
     @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
     @NotNull @NotBlank String name;
     @NotNull @NotBlank String surname
}
```

In controller

```
@PatchMapping(path = "/{personId}", consumes = "application/json-patch+json")
ResponseEntity<Trip> patchPerson(@PathVariable Long personId,
                               @RequestBody final JsonPatch jsonPatch) throws JsonProcessingException, JsonPatchException {
    final Person targetPerson = personRepository.findOne(personId);

    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final JsonNode patch = objectMapper.convertValue(targetPerson, JsonNode.class);
    JsonNode patched = jsonPatch.apply(patch);
    final Person updatedPerson = objectMapper.treeToValue(patched, Person.class);
```

How best to achieve the following behaviour?

- Send all fields as response when a GET request is received.
- Do not allow the user to update the id when sending a Patch. Only the name and surname can be updated.

Adding an example patch I am sending

```
[{ "op": "replace", "path":"/id", "value":"200" }]
```

Comment: Did u have a look at `@JsonView` from jackson. Maybe u can find a nicer solution. Tutorial here : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Comment: Don't Expose Entity at controller level, if the path is getting user id you can remove it from POJO class. Also, please take a look at this https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-update-only-a-subset-of-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/ you need to make Id updatable = false

Comment: @yodamad - I will have a look at JsonView.

Comment: @silentsudo - I can create a different Projo from the entity however I still need to expose an ID as I want to allow the user to request a Person by it's ID. I just don't want them to update it, as that just creates a lot of changes and does not provide any value to the user.

Comment: @shanti can you add a sample JsonPatch you are sending inn requestbody ?

Comment: @Hemant - added example patch to my question

Comment: What is jsonpatch, show this class.

Comment: @improbable - I am using this library https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch

Comment: put its body in the description, ain't nobody got time to go and look for that class

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to expose a DTO instead of entity in the controller. Additionally, you can use `@JsonView` to provide different views for different REST operations. See [this article](https://medium.com/@iamitpatil1993/jackson-jsonview-and-its-meaningful-use-with-spring-boot-rest-5fb2ad58dcfe) for usage of `@JsonView`.

First, you can define views for GET and PATCH methods. Since GET method requires more data than PATCH, `GetView` can extend `PatchView` like this:

```
public class View {
     
     public interface PatchView {}
     public interface GetView extends PatchView {}
}
```

In addition to Person entity, we can have a PersonDto class. `PatchView` will have name and surename while `GetView` extends `PatchView` and has an additional `id` property:

```
class PersonDto {
     
     @JsonView(View.GetView.class)
     Long id;

     @JsonView(View.PatchView.class)
     @NotBlank 
     String name;
     
     @JsonView(View.PatchView.class)
     @NotBlank 
     String surname;
}
```

You can use [Mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/) mapping library to convert Person entity to PersoDto and vice versa.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PersonMapper() {

    PersonDto toPersonDto(Person person);

    Person toPerson(PersonDto personDto);

    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    Person toPerson(PersonDto personDto, @MappingTarget Person person)
}
```

Furthermore, in the controller, you can configure ObjectMapper to include `PatchView` in its deserialization configuration [like this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24545347/16422535):

```
@Autowired     // you should use construtor injection instead of @Autowired
private PersonMapper personMapper;

@PatchMapping(path = "/{personId}", consumes = "application/json-patch+json")
ResponseEntity<Trip> patchPerson(@PathVariable Long personId,
                               @RequestBody JsonPatch jsonPatch) throws JsonProcessingException, JsonPatchException {
    Person targetPerson = personRepository.findOne(personId);
    
    // Mapstruct mapper to map Person to PersonDto
    PersonDto personDto = personMapper.toPersonDto(targetPerson);
    
    // new ObjectMapper instance
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // configure ObjectMapper instance to include JsonView in its deserializer config (View.PatchView.class in this case)
    objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
    objectMapper.setConfig(mapper.getDerializationConfig()
                            .withView(View.PatchView.class));
    
    // apply Json patch to PersonDto
    JsonNode target = objectMapper.convertValue(personDto, JsonNode.class);
    JsonNode patched = jsonPatch.apply(target);
    PersonDto updatedPersonDto = objectMapper.treeToValue(patched, PersonDto.class);

    // convert patched PersonDto back to Person entity using Mapstruct
    Person person = personMapper.toPerson(updatedPersonDto, targetPerson);

    // your additional logic
}
```

Now PATCH method will ignore the `id` property in its deserialization.

**Update:** This workaround basically set properties that are not in @JsonView to null, and mapstruct will ignore null values when converting from DTO back to entity, hence it satisfies the purpose of this post. However, `boolean` type properties will be automatically `set to false` if they are not included in @JsonView. A solution for this problem is using `Boolean` in DTO (not the primitive type boolean) and primitive type `boolean` in entity. The reason why it works because `Boolean` accepts null value and `boolean` does not. If a Boolean property in DTO is null, then mapstruct will not convert it to the mapped boolean property in entity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following code, once the entity is persisted any following updates are discarded by setting id column as `updatable = false`

```
class Person {

     @Id @GeneratedValue
     @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
     Long id;
     @NotNull @NotBlank String name;
     @NotNull @NotBlank String surname
}
```

Comment: Just tried your recommendation. However, the result is that the pojo is still patched successfully and in the the database somehow a new entry is inputted with an auto generated number instead of the one provided by the user. Which is still incorrect handling, as I want to update the same entry and not create a new one.